# How to know if there is a valid 'aps-environment' for an iOS app before submitting to itunesconnect

Tags: ios, xcode

Each time I submit a testing application for push notifications to iTunesConnect I receive a mail saying that I should resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement.

I've been checking and testing with differents solutions proposed on SO, no one of them works yet, but my question is:

Is there a way to know if the build result has a valid aps-environment BEFORE submiting to itunesconnect?

Also, if I run from xCode on my plugged device, the notification works, but if I run it using a device that receive the app using testFlight, it doesnt works.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the description of your problem, it seems that you have only configured the Push Notifications only for development and not for distribution of your App ID.

I am pretty sure that is the only issue causing this scenario. As apple is rejecting the binary that means your App settings confirm to Push Notifications, but the App ID is not configured to support it.

If your App ID is configured for both Development and Distribution, then on your developer account your App ID should 'enabled' against Push Notifications under both 'Development' and 'Distribution'

Comment: I'm sending to iTunes connect to deliver to internal testers (this is development, right?). My on apple devs page, m  APP ID says push notifications for dev: ENABLED, distribution: Configurable (in yellow). But I've another application that have the same config and I dont receive that warning email.

Comment: When you distribute to your internal testers, which provisioning profile do you use for code signing? Development or Distribution??

Comment: I have a strong feeling that you are signing your code with a distribution provisioning profile